# How to stop a JButton's height from changing after adding an underline?

Tags: java, html, jbutton, preferredsize

So I have a `JButton` that when you move your mouse over it, an underline appears using HTML. However when the underline is added it makes the `JButton` a tad bit larger than it's supposed to be.

I have tried a few things like

`button.setMaximumSize(button.getPreferredSize());`

before the underline is added, but I haven't been able to fix it. So how do I make sure the height stays the same, regardless if the underline is present or not.

I have a sample class below that demonstrates the problem (I couldn't get it to have the exact same severity, but it's enough to show the problem).

**SAMPLE CLASS**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalButtonUI;

public class UnderlineSample extends JFrame {
    public UnderlineSample() {
        super("Underline Sample");
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 150));

        String text =
                "<html>"
                    + "<p style = 'border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0,0); box-sizing: border-box;'>"
                        + "<span style = 'color: rgb(0, 0, 255); font-weight: bold;'>"
                            + "Sample"
                        + "</span> "
                        + " underline button"
                    + "</p>"
               + "</html>";
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.setFont(new Font("", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        button.setFocusable(false);
        button.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        button.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        button.setUI(new MetalButtonUI());
        button.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        button.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

        button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                String s =
                    "<html>"
                        + "<p style = 'border-bottom: 1px solid black; box-sizing: border-box;'>"
                            + "<span style = 'color: rgb(0, 0, 255); font-weight: bold;'>"
                                + "Sample"
                            + "</span> "
                            + " underline button"
                        + "</p>"
                   + "</html>";
                button.setText(s);
            }

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                String s =
                    "<html>"
                        + "<p style = 'border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0,0); box-sizing: border-box;'>"
                            + "<span style = 'color: rgb(0, 0, 255); font-weight: bold;'>"
                                + "Sample"
                            + "</span> "
                            + " underline button"
                        + "</p>"
                   + "</html>";
                button.setText(s);
            }
        });

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0; gbc.gridy = 0; gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc.weightx = 1; gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; gbc.ipady = 10;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 5, 10);

        add(button, gbc);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new UnderlineSample();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rendering of `html/css` in Swing does not have support for all css styles. Case in point `rgba` does not work (you can test this yourself by adding a colored border using `rgba` that you expect to be rendered rather than one with alpha 0 and see the result).

In other words, the border with `rgba` is not being rendered, hence the change in size when you add a renderable border-bottom with the `MouseListener.mouseEntered`. You can trick it by using `rgb` that has the same color as the background color. Something like:

```
<p style = 'border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(200,200,200); box-sizing: border-box;'>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I do however have one last question. When trying this I noticed that spaces between the rgb values caused it to not work. For example, while this worked: `rgb(4,137,181);`, this did not: `rgb(4, 137, 181);`. do you know why that is?

Comment: Glad it worked. `I noticed that spaces between the rgb values caused it to not work` Whitespace is [technically allowed](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgb-color) - 'tis a demonstration that the Swing css/html parser is far from perfect.